# What is the best way to get my Samsung Note 3 SM-N900V to at least Nougat 7.0?

Tags: rooting, samsung-galaxy-note-3

The step by step examples have holes in their solution for one reason or another. 
I need to:
a. USB debug (easy)
b. Root w/o KNOX violation
c. Install TWRP
d. Flash a ROM like Apply a custom ROM like RR-N-v5.8.2

Has anyone done this in 2020? It seems like links for these solutions vanish for some reason. This like  ArabicTools and Root_de_la_Vega-SM-N900V.7z seemed to have vanished.

Comment: never heard about b. but still learning..

Answer (score 0):

found a non corrupt Root_de_la_Vega-SM-N900V.7z here:
http://rootjunkysdl.com/files/?dir=Galaxy%20Note%203/MI9%20build%20root
http://rootjunkysdl.com/files/Galaxy%20Note%203/MI9%20build%20root/Root_de_la_Vega-SM-N900V.7z
I am about to give it a go myself.